# Global undefined inside anonymous callback function

Tags: javascript

I have a few javascript functions. The global var is initialized in f1, which then calls f2, where they are obviously defined since its called later. However, its undefined inside the anonymous function inside f2.

```
var global = [];

function f1() {
    global = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
    f2();
}

function f2() {

    // HERE global = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]

    for(var i = 0; i < global.length; i++) {

       f3(function(thisIsSomeJSONdata) {

        console.log(global[i].id); // cannot read id of undefined

        // HERE global[0], global[1], global[2] === undefined

        global[0].name = "A";
        global[1].name = "B";
        global[2].name = "C";
       });
    }
}

function f3(callback) {

    var thisIsSomeJSONdata;
    // timeout to simulate AJAX delay
    setTimeout(function(){
      callback(thisIsSomeJSONdata);
    },3000);
}
```

Even if the anonymous function copies variables and creates a new context inside, the values should be as defined previously.

Comment: Looks good on my end.

Comment: Try to run it in console. Works without the loop in f2, but has undefined with the loop in f2.

Comment: It's still okay. And should always be okay if the execution order is as given, and if you aren't redefining global anywhere. Try stepping with the debugger to see if that happens.

Comment: can you recreate the issue using http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n2RUr/1/ - the values logged in console looks good

Comment: your fiddle is working correctly

Comment: Adding timeout to f3 (to simulate AJAX delay) has the undefined issue. Also, I think i = globals.length  inside the anonymous callback, since it has incremented till the conditional by the time AJAX call returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a different matter with async calls. Your for loop executes before `callback` is called, so `i` evaluates to `3` once it gets called. 
You'll have to provide a closure for it, like this:

```
var global = [];

function f1() {
    global = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
    f2();
}

function f2() {

    // HERE global = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]

    for(var i = 0; i < global.length; i++) {

       (function(i) { 
         f3(function(thisIsSomeJSONdata) {
         console.debug(global);
         console.log(global[i].id); // cannot read id of undefined

         // HERE global[0], global[1], global[2] === undefined

         global[0].name = "A";
         global[1].name = "B";
         global[2].name = "C";
        });
       })(i);
    }
}

function f3(callback) {

    var thisIsSomeJSONdata;
    // timeout to simulate AJAX delay
    setTimeout(function(){
      callback(thisIsSomeJSONdata);
    },3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Though even if i evaluates to length (which is 2), globals[2].id is 3, not sure why its undefined.

Comment: The length is 3. When length is 0, array is empty.

Comment: I advise you to grab a decent book (perhaps Crockford's?) if you have long-term plans with JavaScript, I promise - it will save you a lot of head-banging.

Comment: Yes, I have Javascript - the good parts. Should finish reading that. Its a great book.

Comment: I am used to frameworks that deal with a lot of issues so have not encountered a ton of them.

Comment: Check out coffescript, and other splat compilers ;) They really make a difference.